# Access Mac "Site" folder as local host from Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost

I have successfully accessed images from my "XXAMP" server on my Windows machine to populate a gridview on an Android emulator, but am having no luck on my mac. Here is what works on my windows:

```
"http://10.0.2.2/helloGridView/imgs/sample_0.jpg",
```

and I tried this on mac (utilizing Sites folder):

```
"http://172.20.23.1/~verityt/helloGridView/imgs/sample_0.jpg",
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same form as in windows, however note that if you're using the "Sites" folder on mac the url is going to be in a different form. For example, here's what works for me on my mac:

http://10.0.2.2/~gmanish/noteit.web/controller/appcontroller.php

10.0.2.2 is the localhost loopback address. gmanish is my user name. Everything else, is as present on disk relative to my root folder (/Users/gmanish/Sites).

Comment: Can you access your mac site from a browser on the same machine.

Comment: What about http://127.0.0.1/~verityt or http://localhost/~verityt? I'm assuming 172.* is the ip of your mac machine?